Running detox build returns error android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element
When running detox build -c android.emu.release, I get the error:
/android/app/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/dev/release/tempFile1ProcessTestManifest8635081709038100528.xml
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>.
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

The activity <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker is not even on my AndroidManifest.xml so I can't include an android:exported="true"
I am on detox v20.23.0.
I tried cleaning up and rebuilding the project successfully with the following:
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
yarn react-native run-android --mode=devdebug --appId=com.mypackage.reactnative
However, it fails when running detox build.
